# Detecting Browser type and applying relevant styling

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, css

I've built a “in-house” web application for my company mainly using PHP/MySQL that’s in use in a few departments in my company.

I styled the site (I suppose naively) so that it would work well and look good using Chrome and Firefox. Until recently this wasn’t a problem as everyone using it was using those browsers.

However, a new department has been added to the list of users and they all use an old version of IE and they don’t have permissions to upgrade or install any software on their own machines. I found one or two issues but not many as a result.

I want to be able to detect what browser someone is using and apply a particular styling accordingly.

I'm not the best at JavaScript but I suppose that would be how it's done? But how?

Comment: [google search](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how%20to%20find%20out%20if%20user%20is%20using%20internet%20explorer)

Comment: [Read up on Modernizr.](http://modernizr.com/)

Comment: This is not a bad question, I too have worked on an in-house application with a similar requirement, as the web application behaved/looked slightly differently on IE8 and that was a corporate requirement. I'll post my solution int he answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for something like:

```
    var navigator = function (){
        var ua= navigator.userAgent, tem, 
        M= ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*([\d\.]+)/i) || [];
        if(/trident/i.test(M[1])){
            tem=  /\brv[ :]+(\d+(\.\d+)?)/g.exec(ua) || [];
            return 'IE '+(tem[1] || '');
        }
        M= M[2]? [M[1], M[2]]:[navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
        if((tem= ua.match(/version\/([\.\d]+)/i))!= null) M[2]= tem[1];
        return M.join(' ');
    };
//usage
//IE < 10
        if(navigator()[0] == "I" && navigator().match(/\d+/) < 10){
            alert('You are using '+navigator+'.Please update to version >= 10');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can force IE to load a compatibility mode.Hope its I.E 8 version that you are looking for.
Use the below :

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
```

Give this a try. You can change the versions as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

put this in `head`

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

more here: http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

or use a custom build of modernizr for feature detection more then browser detection:

http://www.modernizr.com

Answer (score 0):

You can, in your html, check if the user is using IE with

```
<!--[if IE]>
Place styles here for IE (so all your scripts and links to stylesheets and scripts)
<![endif]-->
```

To revert back to the other styles:

```
<!--[if !IE]>
Place styles here for not IE (so all your scripts and links to stylesheets and scripts that you were using before)
<![endif]-->
```

You will need to have both of these in the same document to make sure that the styles do not clash with eachother.

http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/html/detect/detect-ie.html

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use, as others have mentioned, two different style elements, one for IE and one for non IE:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/blahblah-ie8.css"/>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if !IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/blahblah.css"/>
<![endif]-->
```

You can target either a single version of IE or all versions

`<!--[if IE 8]>` OR `<!--[if IE]>`

The other thing that you might want is to warn users when your application is not supported at all in a browser. So as corporate software, the webapp might only support FF, Chrome and IE - you dont want users clogging up your help desk with queries about why something is broken in Opera or Maxthon.

To this end, I've used a Javascript that is loaded at the start, that detects a the user agent and displays a floating div at the top of the screen that displays a message stating that the user can use the browser but it is not supported.